# How to move s3 data to redshift based on event trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

EMR spark write final dataframe into s3 and from there move the data to s3, how can i move the data to redshift based on s3 event . ie once data reached s3? have any services or technic available ? please share those details.

1. expolred Data pipeline - ONLY on demand and scheduled.. no event based trigger
2. Lambda - limited session - copy TB of data.. NOT sure will it support.

Comment: S3 have notifications. So you can trigger lambda on a PUT of a new data,  and the lambda will jump start the redshift.

Comment: will it support TB of data.. i think lambda have limited session. please correct me if am wrong.can u please share the url to refer

Comment: Lambda is only used to start/trigger redshift [COPY](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) operation from S3. So actual copping procedure is done by redshift.

Comment: Here is tutorial how to copy from s3 in redshift: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-loading-data.html

Comment: I agree,, actual copy is doing from redshift.. my question is , Lambda will wait till copy command execution complet

Comment: Don't think so. COPY is internal operation of redshift. Here is one example of doing this using lambda. You could also trigger data pipelilne to do this, i think.

Comment: Have any example related to Java.. 1. for data pipeline and 2. copy command.. Which option would you prefer.. share you thoughts.. as beginner strugle to choose the best one..